# Linq: How to make this work

Tags: linq

I have this Linq statement:

```
List<string> phoneNumbers = from t
                            in fixedLineData
                            select t.phoneNumber.Distinct();
```

Basically what I want is a distinct list of strings sent back from the LINQ query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it

```
  var phoneNumbers =
      (from t in fixedLineData 
      select t.phoneNumber)
      .Distinct().ToList();
```

But you might as well skip the query-syntax:

```
 var phoneNumbers =
      fixedLineData 
      .Select (t => t.phoneNumber)
      .Distinct()
      .ToList();
```

The `.ToList()` will make the resulting type `IList<string>`

Comment: Excellent. And I see it is even possible this way to declare it as a fully fledged List<string>

Comment: Possible, yes. But I would use `var phoneNumbers2 = new List<string>(phoneNumbers);` , after removing `.ToList()`.